# C’è una regola per l’ordine degli elementi in aggettivi composti di nazionalità?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Mi sono sempre chiesto se esista una regola per l'ordine nei casi di doppia nazionalità .

Mi spiego: una persona con nazionalità italiana e americana si dice **italo-*americana***, una inglese e italiana **anglo-*italiana*** (ma si usa anche **italo-*inglese***), una francese e italiana **italo-*francese*** (anche qui l'uso di **franco-*italiano*** è comune), una francese e tedesca **franco-*tedesca***.

Esiste una regola sull'ordine degli aggettivi o si va "a sentimento"?

Comment: Italo francese e italo inglese, le versioni opposte non si usano quasi mai, sono poco conosciute.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Sara8! Qui ci aspettiamo una risposta più approfondita e argomentata. Per questa ragione il tuo post è stato convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 5):

Pare ci sia un ordine determinante-determinato, com’è normale in italiano. Solo il secondo elemento infatti porta le informazioni grammaticali sul genere e il numero, mentre il primo sembra fungere da prefissoide, e quindi da attributo.

Per esempio, *italoamericano* indica un americano d’origini italiane, non un italiano di origini americane. *Francocanadese*, allo stesso modo, si riferirà a un canadese di lingua francese; *[italofrancese](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italo-francesi)* a un francese di origini italiane; *angloitaliano* a un italiano di discendenza inglese, e cosí via.

Mi sembra inoltre che non sempre sia possibile creare un aggettivo composto. Una persona francese di origini tedesche non è un *germanofrancese*, ma un francese di origini tedesche. Ciò dipende anche dalla possibilità di ricavare o no un prefissoide dal demonimo: da *italiano* si è fatto *italo*-; per *inglese* c’è *anglo*-; per *francese* *franco*-; per *spagnolo* *ispano*-. Elementi come *svizzero*- o *german*(*ic*)*o*- usati come prefissoidi risultano piuttosto pesanti e «antieconomici».

In altri casi il prefissoide esisterebbe, ma il miscuglio di nazionalità è cosí raro che non si è potuto creare un aggettivo composto: per esempio, esiste *luso*- per *portoghese* («[**luso**fono](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lusofono/)»), ma non esiste *lusoitaliano*, *lusoinglese*, ecc.

Comment: Svizzero-italiano (-tedesco, -francese) si usa, ma il prefisso corrisponde all'aggettivo quindi non se ne riconosce la differenza

Comment: Uno _svizzeroitaliano_ (pl. _svizzeroitaliani_!) però sarebbe un italiano di origini svizzere, cosa, penso, non comunissima. Uno svizzero d’origini italiane, al contrario, sarebbe un _italosvizzero_.

Comment: Essendo italo-tedesco (un tedesco nato e quasi sempre vissuto in Italia) ed avendo frequentato la Scuola Germanica di Roma ho incontrato molto spesso l'aggettivo _italo-tedesco_ (e mai _germano-italiano_ o simili), ma in tutti questi anni non ho mai percepito una relazione determinante-determinato fra _italo_ e _tedesco_. Le _relazioni italo-tedesche_ sono simmetriche (lasciamo da parte, vi prego, la politica), come anche gli _accordi bilaterali italo-tedeschi_, eccetera. Ho sempre pensato che la scelta dell'ordine fosse dettata unicamente dall'eufonia.

Comment: Però «italo-tedesche» in «relazioni italo-tedesche» è una cosa diversa: non si parla di una nazionalità, ma di un rapporto. Per questo, in questo caso sarebbe utile mantenere anche il trattino. Ha ragione, comunque, a mettere in evidenza la questione dell’eufonia che permette o vieta di creare aggettivi composti: infatti non sempre è possibile farlo. Quanto a _italotedesco_ in riferimento a una persona, io l’interpreto come «tedesco di origine italiana». Una persona di nazionalità italiana ma di genitori tedeschi lo chiamerei, prolissamente, «italiano di origini tedesche».

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu Non ho ancora accettato la risposta perché pensavo al caso di trattati bilaterali o simili: qui manca la questione dell'origine e nulla indica quale aggettivo debba essere prima. Parliamo quindi di italotedesco, svizzerofrancese, francoamericano, etc... In questo caso vi sono regole precise o è solo questione di suoni?

Comment: @RiccardoI. Penso che in questo caso si scelga l’aggettivo piú diffuso. Ma sentiamo altri pareri.